# Solve $c(2x)-2c(x)=2\alpha \int_0^{2x}e^{c(z)}\ z\ dz,$ $x \in (0,\infty)$, $\alpha \in [-1, 1]$.

Tags: measure-theory, delay-differential-equations

I want to solve for the measurable function $c(x)$ for the following equation:
$$c(2x)-2c(x)=2\alpha \int_0^{2x}e^{c(z)}\ z\ dz.$$
Where $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $\alpha \in [-1, 1].$

So I continued by assuming $c\in \mathcal{C}^2$ then:
$$c'(2x)-c'(x)=4\alpha\ x\ e^{c(2x)}$$
Differentiating again:
$$2c''(2x)-c''(x)=4\alpha\ \left(e^{c(2x)}+2x\ e^{c(2x)}\ c'(2x)\right)$$
Letting $w=2x$ and substituting $c'(2x)-c'(x)=4\alpha\ x\ e^{c(2x)}$ we get:
$$2c''(2x)-c''(x)={c'(2x)-c'(x)\over x}+2c'(2x)(c'(2x)-c'(x))$$
$$wc''(w)-{w\over 2}c''({w\over 2})=c'({w})-c'({w\over 2})+wc'(w)^2-wc'(w)c'({w\over 2})$$
Any hints on how to solve the DDE given a boundary conditions of $c(0)=0$ and $c(\infty)=-2\alpha.$

Comment: The 2's on the LHS would cancel with the RHS, then a 4 comes from $z=2x$ and $(2x)^{'}=2$.

Comment: Maybe the following transformations give some insight: First set $\tau = \log (2x), \tau_0 = \log 2$. The differential equation becomes $\dot{c}(\tau) - \dot{c}(\tau - \tau_0) = F(\tau,c(\tau))$ for a suitable $F$, where $\dot{c}$ is the derivative with respect to $\tau$. Next add these equations at $\tau, \tau - \tau_0, \dots$ to obtain the delay differential equation $\dot{c}(\tau) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty F(\tau - j \tau_0, c(\tau - j \tau_0))$, for $- \infty < \tau < \infty$. Linearize about $c = 0$ and $c = - 2 \alpha$ to obtain information about the behavior of $c$ at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: For $\alpha \ne 0$, the equation cannot have a solution with a nontrivial limit at $\infty$, since in that case the RHS becomes unbounded.